# Why does putting numpy arrays in a dict seemingly result in a single set of Numpy arrays being accessible from multiple variables?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

So I'm a little confused at the moment and just hoping for some clarification. I have some code:

```
bins = {
"Number 1": numpy.zeros(50, dtype=int),
"Number 2": numpy.zeros(50, dtype=int),
"Number 3": numpy.zeros(50, dtype=int),
"Number 4": numpy.zeros(50, dtype=int),
"Number 5": numpy.zeros(50, dtype=int)}


for index, key in enumerate(bins.keys()):
    for numberDrawn in dataset[:, index]:
       bins[key][numberDrawn-1] += 1

probabilities = bins
            
for key in probabilities.keys():
    probabilities[key] = probabilities[key]/probabilities[key].sum()

cumulativeDistributionFunction = probabilities

for key in cumulativeDistributionFunction:
    for index, x in enumerate(cumulativeDistributionFunction[key]):
        if index == 0: 
            continue
        else:
            cumulativeDistributionFunction[key][index] = cumulativeDistributionFunction[key][index]+cumulativeDistributionFunction[key][index-1]
```

where dataset is just an external csv file that was read in using numpy and structured as [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]...].

Now I was expecting that when I would do "probabilities = bins" and "cumulativeDistributionFunction = probabilities" I would end up with 3 dictionaries, each with 5 numpy arrays in them. However when I run this code, I appear to instead have 1 dictionary with 5 numpy arrays that I can access (almost like a weird pointer type situation) from the other 2 variable names.

To try and be more clear, what I mean is, it seems like there is a single block of memory that I am accessing via 3 different variables. Is this expected and I'm doing something wrong?

I'm asking as I was hoping to have 3 independent variables but I'm not sure why this is happening.

Cheers.

Comment: `probabilities = bins` just gives another name to `bins`.  No copying.  This is basic python behavior.

Comment: You have 3 names, but still only one dict, and within that 5 arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Cheers for the link, I wasn't aware this behaviour was thing in python for all data types beyond lists (though in hindsight I guess it's obvious)